# Amazon cognito authentication flow with saml

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, amazon-cognito

I want the amazon cognito signin integration for my application.

Say login end point

**https:.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=app id>&redirect_uri=application end point**

Above login end points and login flow goes well with my application and i am able to achieve the desired behavior (login to my application using cognito)

Now i want the above login page request as SAML. Can we achieve using amazon cognito

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can authenticate users using SAML. I myself tried O365 login but I am stuck at one point because I'm a bit new to Android programming and due to the lack of proper documentation by Amazon itself.

[SAML With Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834593/android-cognito-with-saml-o365)

Refer above link where I have asked a question. There contains all the information you need to achieve SAML authentication. I'm trying to log in from an Android application which I'm still unable to do. But through the auto generated UI by Cognito I can log in using my office email and password.

If you need to know anything feel free to circulate it through this thread.
You can disregard all the Android related content from my question and follow the excellent article I've linked to it and get the SAML authentication up and running.